# Playing sound, passing url to flash

Tags: actionscript-3

If I have a url to a mp3, can I pass this in some way to a flash file so that it will play it? How could I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An example from the [actionscript reference](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/media/Sound.html):

```
package {
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.*;
    import flash.media.Sound;
    import flash.media.SoundChannel;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;

    public class SoundExample extends Sprite {
        private var url:String = "MySound.mp3";
        private var song:SoundChannel;

        public function SoundExample() {
            var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
            var soundFactory:Sound = new Sound();
            soundFactory.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
            soundFactory.addEventListener(Event.ID3, id3Handler);
            soundFactory.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioErrorHandler);
            soundFactory.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, progressHandler);
            soundFactory.load(request);
            song = soundFactory.play();
        }

        private function completeHandler(event:Event):void {
            trace("completeHandler: " + event);
        }

        private function id3Handler(event:Event):void {
            trace("id3Handler: " + event);
        }

        private function ioErrorHandler(event:Event):void {
            trace("ioErrorHandler: " + event);
        }

        private function progressHandler(event:ProgressEvent):void {
            trace("progressHandler: " + event);
        }
    }
}
```

You can combine the above with the parameters of the [LoaderInfo](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/LoaderInfo.html#parameters): Those are flashvars passed by html or parameters in the url used to call the swf.

In the reference are a lot of good examples,, I mostly learned actionscript by [gotoandlearn.com](http://www.gotoandlearn.com) and [the reference](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/).

Answer (score 0):

You can set pass the url into the swf on load by setting a flashvar. You can set flashvars in 2 ways.. using the param element on your embed code or you can just append them to the url of the swf, the result is the same.

http://blog.six4rty.ch/tutorials/flash-flashvars-in-as3/

If you dont know the mp3 url when you load the swf you must use the ExternalInterface actionscript methods to register some actionscript functions so you can call them from the webpage's javascript. So in your flash movie you could have

```
function setSrc( mp3URL ) { ... }
function play(){ ... }
function stop(){ ... }
```

register each of these with External interface

```
ExternalInterface.addCallback( 'setSrc', setSrc ); 
ExternalInterface.addCallback( 'play', play ); 
ExternalInterface.addCallback( 'stop', stop );
```

Now you can use them from javascript.